# Enable AutoLayout for old source code in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, autoresizingmask

The project was written long ago, using "autoresizingmask", "Top and Bottom layout guides".

Now I wish to update to auto layout. I couldn't find the option "Use AutoLayout in Interface Builder."

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `Use Auto Layout` option is no longer visible to `Xcode 11`. But you can open the same project in `Xcode 10` and there you can enable this.

[image]

My Xcode version is 10.2.1.

[image]

You can download older versions from here in case you don't have one.:
[Xcode 10.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2.1/Xcode_10.2.1.xip)

Just sign in with your Apple-id and start downloading.

I hope this may help you.